# Problema sincronizar propiedad visibility

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un script de tal forma que cuando los id “potencia2” y “potencia3” tengan visibility=’hidden’, los id “epotencia2” y “epotencia3” se pongan también hidden. Y que cuando los id “potencia2” y “potencia3” tengan visibility: visible; que los id “epotencia2” y “epotencia3” cambien también a visibility: visible.

Pego la parte del código y el script que estoy intentando hacer. Estoy haciendo el apaño llamando a una función cada 100 milisegundos pero el script no funciona.

Espero vuestras respuestas,
Gracias.

```
    <script>

    //setInterval(function(){ obtenerHora() }, 500);


    actualizarVisibility(){

      var visibilityPotencia2 = document.getElementById("potencia2").style.visibility;
      var visibilityPotencia3 = document.getElementById("potencia3").style.visibility;

      document.getElementsById("epotencia2").style.visibility = visibilityPotencia2;
      document.getElementById("epotencia3").style.visibility = visibilityPotencia3;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        actualizarVisibility();

    }

    setInterval(function(){ actualizarVisibility() }, 100);



</script>

<%"    Potencia 2    %>
    <div class="centro">
        <div id="pot2">
            <div class="etiquetapot2 ancho-automatico" id="epotencia2" title="Potencia contratada P2" style="visibility:hidden;">
                <span class="asterisco">*</span>
                <label for="potencia2" class="edp-visibility">
                    <%= appl->texto('POT_CONTR_P2')%>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="potencia2" id="potencia2" maxlength="6" onkeydown="return Analizar(event,'potencia2','6');" onkeyup="AddListItem_nueva_venta(this);"
                     onchange="valida_num('potencia2');cambia_potencias('POT2');mostrar_fechas_cc(event);sel_pot(this,'POT2');"
                     class="select_editable select_peq <%=estilo_campos%> " style="width:65px" value="<%= aux_pot2%>" <%=readOnly%> <%=disabled%>/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 <%"    Potencia 3    %>
    <div class="derecha">
        <div id="pot3">
            <div class="etiquetapot3 ancho-automatico" id="epotencia3" title="Potencia contratada P3" style="visibility:hidden;">

                <span class="asterisco">*</span>
                <label for="potencia3">
                    <%= appl->texto('POT_CONTR_P3')%>
                </label>
                <input name="potencia3" id="potencia3" maxlength="6" type="text" value="<%= aux_pot3t%>" onkeydown="return Analizar(event,'potencia3','6');" onkeyup="AddListItem_nueva_venta(this);"
                    onchange="valida_num('potencia3');cambia_potencias('POT3');mostrar_fechas_cc(event); sel_pot(this,'POT3');"
                    class="select_editable select_peq <%=estilo_campos%>" style="width:65px" <%=readOnly%> value="<%= aux_pot3%>" <%=disabled%> />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás cambiando la `visibility` de `potencia2` y `potencia3`?

Comment: @Kiko_L es código que no hice yo, y desconozco qué método es el que cambia el visibility de "potencia2" y "potencia3". Sé que lo cambia según unas opciones que elijas en un select que hay más arriba. Lo que pasa es que sólo cambia el input y no me cambia el label. Por eso estoy intentando hacer un apaño con javaScript. Lo único que sé es que cambiando el visibility de epotencia2/epotencia3 me lo aplica también al label

Comment: Pues lo suyo sería intentar averiguar dónde cambia la visibility de esos inputs porque chequear cada "x" milisegundos si son visibles o no no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Te recomiendo que intentes entender el código que has *heredado* y averigües cómo cambian los otros campos. Lo que pides en la pregunta sueña a *chapuza* (con todo el respeto)

Comment: me parece tienes mal escrito el nombre del método para obtener un elemento por su id, que debería ser `getElementById()` en singular

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si el fallo está en que te estás equivocando al llamar al segundo getElementsById

Tu código:

```
document.getElementsById("epotencia2").style.visibility = visibilityPotencia3;
```

Lo que debería ser:

```
document.getElementById("epotencia2").style.visibility = visibilityPotencia3;
```

Ten cuidado porque algún navegador la ausencia de la propiedad *visibility* en lugar de devolverte una cadena vacía puede devolverte *"null"*.

Yo haría así:

```
actualizarVisibility(){
    var visibilityPotencia2 = document.getElementById("potencia2").style.visibility;
    var visibilityPotencia3 = document.getElementById("potencia3").style.visibility;

    document.getElementById("epotencia2").style.visibility = ( visibilityPotencia2 ) ? visibilityPotencia2 : "visible";
    document.getElementById("epotencia3").style.visibility = ( visibilityPotencia3 ) ? visibilityPotencia3 : "visible";
}
```

Por otro lado es ineficiente tener un setInterval para eso. ¿Por qué no, ya que el input en el que cambias, supongo, la visibilidad desde otro script, es hijo del elemento que después ocultas en función de su visibilidad, atacas directamente al padre **epotenciaXX**?

Me explico, en lugar da asignar la visibilidad al input y tener una función que comprueba si este es o no visible para ocultar el padre, asigna la visibilidad directamente al padre y te ahorras el **setInterval**.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: seguro que `getElementsById()` existe? es decir en plural?

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que `getElementById` debería ser `getElementsById`? Como dice @element, no existe esa función. De hecho esto sería contradictorio ya que los ids deben ser únicos en el DOM.

Comment: Cierto @element, me equivoqué al redactar. En su código tiene una en plural y creo que por eso le falla.